# SQL - if or something else

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

When I execute a SQL query I get next:

```
select  Item.No_, Entry.Quantity, MinMax.MaxQuantity, Entry.Location, Item.MainLocation
FROM Item
join Entry
on Item.No_ = Entry.[Item No_]
join MinMax
on Item.No_ = MinMax.Item No_
```

[image]

I want if Quantity from MainLocation is 30, to full in another location Quantity to MaxQuantity. That means

MainLocation:A1 has 30 Quantity,

but Location

A2 has 2

A3 has 12

A4 has 1

I want to full quantity to MaxQuantity, to take from A1 and I give A2, A3, A4 and reduce A1 .

I want next to get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add both tables' data as well.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use

Comment: sql server management studio

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. please clarify.

Comment: i want from first table to get second table. but from loaction A1 Quantity to stay 30, and for location A2 Quantity (2) is MaxQuantiy (5) and A1 reduce 30 - 3 (becase I add 3 in location A2 in Quantity to full to MaxQuantity)...

Comment: The query seems incomplete (no location in join criteria to minmax). What are your table's keys? It looks like both entry and minmax have the unique key [Item No_] + Location. Is this correct? (If so, why do you have two tables instead of just one?)

Comment: The unique key is [Item No_]

Comment: How then can you have different Quantity and different MaxQuantity for the same item???

Comment: becase it is in different location

Comment: But if the **unique** key is [Item No_], then there is exactly one record per [Item No_] in the tables, hence only one Location and one Quantity per [Item No_].

Comment: And do you want to only select the data or update the tables?

Comment: Ah, you are still there. So again: what are the tables' unique keys?

Comment: please can you put the question back, currently it is empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with InitialQuery as 
(
    select  Item.No_, Entry.Quantity, MinMax.MaxQuantity, Entry.Location, Item.MainLocation
    from Item
    join Entry on Item.No_ = Entry.[Item No_]
    join MinMax on Item.No_ = MinMax.Item No_
)
, Sources as
(
    select * from InitialQuery
    where Location=MainLocation and Quantity=30
)
, Destinations as 
(
    select 
        i.*,
        i.MaxQuantity - i.Quantity 'Needed'
    from Sources s
    join InitialQuery i on i.No_=s.No_ and i.MainLocation=s.MainLocation and i.Location<>s.Location
)
select 
    s.No_,
    (s.Quantity - d.NoTransferred) 'Quantity',
    s.MaxQuantity,
    s.Location,
    s.MainLocation
from Sources s
join (
        select No_, MainLocation, sum(Needed) 'NoTransferred' from Destinations group by No_, MainLocation
    ) d on d.No_=s.No_ and d.MainLocation=s.MainLocation
union all
select 
    No_,
    MaxQuantity 'Quantity',
    MaxQuantity,
    Location,
    MainLocation
from Destinations
```